# Proof that expected value of estimators for Ordinary Least Squares estimators equals the optimal solution?

Tags: linear-regression

I'm doing a linear regression master's course right now and the prof wrote "Properties of OLS estimators is that they are unbiased estimators:
$$\mathbb{E}(\hat{B})=\mathbb{E}[(X^TX)^{-1}X^Ty]$$
$$=\mathbb{E}[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T(X\beta+\epsilon)]$$
$$=\beta$$

$X$ defines the inputs to the regression (They could be multidimensional that's why $X$ is denoted as a matrix) $y$ is the correct correlated values then $\beta$ is the parameters to the linear function and $epsilon$ is the error residual between $X\beta$ and $y.$

I feel like there was a bit of a jump there how did they get from the 2nd line to the last line? How did the expectation of all that suddenly vanish and just equal $\beta?$

Comment: $(X^TX)^{-1}X^T(X\beta+\epsilon)=\beta+(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[(X^TX)^{-1}X^T(X\beta + \epsilon)] &= 
(X^TX)^{-1}(X^TX)\mathbb{E}[\beta]+(X^TX)^{-1}X^T\mathbb{E}[\epsilon] \\
&= \beta + 0
\end{align*}
Where the first equality follows from linearity of expectation and in the second we use that the expected value of $\epsilon$ is $0$.

Comment: How come only $\beta$ and $\epsilon$ stay within the expectation but everything else is on the outside?

Comment: If $A$ is a $k\times n$ matrix and $Y$ a $n$-dimensional random vektor, then $\mathbb{E}[AY]=A \mathbb{E} [Y]$. This is because expectation is linear and $y\mapsto By$ is a linear transformation. You can easily verify simply by computing the $i'th$ entry of each side of the equation using the definition of matrix/vector multiplication.

Comment: Also note that the only thing that is random in the equation is $\epsilon$.